# Cannot access JSON data on datamuse api

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects, p5.js

I have done this on p5.js:

```
  var str = "apple";
  var url = 'https://api.datamuse.com/words?ml='+str+ '&max=2';
  var data = loadJSON(url);
  console.log(data);
```

And the data is showing up on console as:

```
  [
      {
          "word": "malus pumila",
          "score": 23704,
          "tags": [
             "syn",
             "n",
             "prop"
           ]
      },
      {
          "word": "orchard apple tree",
          "score": 23704,
          "tags": [
             "syn",
             "n"
          ]
      }
 ]
```

Which is as expected, but the problem arises when you try to access the 'word ' key's value of say the first object. I have tried doing:

```
    console.log(data[0]);
```

which outputs 'undefinded' in the console. I also tried looping through each of the items of the object, by say, a forEach loop, but nothing is working. I even tried:

```
    console.log(Object.entries(data)[0]);
```

and it shows undefined.

Console logging `typeof data` outputs 'object'.
How can this be done?

**Update: Bug fixed**
Due to [Nenad Vracar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4620771/nenad-vracar)'s help, I successfully managed to solve this. My code is currently hosted in codepen. [DEMO](https://codepen.io/subham-kharel/pen/JvZvVR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load json in `preload` function and then use it in `setup`, also it appears that data is object and not an array so you can use some object method to iterate it.
[**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OZEpeo?editors=0010)

```js
var data;

function preload() {
  var str = "apple";
  var url = "https://api.datamuse.com/words?ml=" + str + "&max=2";
  data = loadJSON(url);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  console.log(data[0].word);

  Object.values(data).forEach(obj => console.log(obj.word));
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  noLoop();
}
```

Not sure if this is possible with p5 but you could use library like `Axios` to create http `GET` request to your url from `setup` or any other part of code and parameters can by dynamic. [**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OZEpeo?editors=1010)

```
function setup() {
  const canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
  canvas.mousePressed(() => {
    var str = "apple";
    var url = "https://api.datamuse.com/words?ml=" + str + "&max=2";

    axios.get(url)
      .then(({data}) => {
        data.forEach(({word}) => console.log(word))
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  })
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  noLoop();
}
```

Comment: Yeah this seems to be working, the only plot twist is; im actually geting the str when the user hovers over the string, so loading it in preload, i wouldnt have any clue which words to query. Is there a way around this?